# Routing for multiple variable in a request string

Tags: python, flask

I am having difficulty understanding how to grab variables from a request string in flask. I'm pretty sure this syntax is wrong, but can someone help me understand how to grab multiple variables from the request string?

```
@restServer.route('/end_point/<foo>&<bar>')
def like_provider(self,foo,bar):
```

Which syntax should I use when sending data?

```
http://url/foo&bar
```

OR

```
http://url/var=foo&var2=bar
```

In the second case, how would I write the routing code in Flask?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two parts to a URL your view needs to care about: the URL path, and the query string. Both your examples are *just path elements*, really, the query string is everything after the `?`.

It really depends on how your web application is supposed to be interacted with; a URL usually represents one resource, with the query string representing, well, a query on that resource.

Compare `/users/102324` with `/users?name=Joe+Soap`; the former represents *one* user (with the id `102323`, the latter URL is for *all users*, but includes a search for users matching a given name.

The *path* is the part you match with the route config; it matches your pattern exactly; for your two examples, the `foo` and `bar` placeholders capture everything (except for the `/` character); so both your URLs would work, and simply result in different values for `foo` and `bar`:

```
http://url/end_point/foo&bar  -> {'foo': 'foo', 'bar': 'bar'}
http://url/end_point/var=foo&var2=bar  -> {'foo': 'var=foo', 'bar': 'var2=bar'}
```

But you'd normally *not* use `&` in a URL path.

The query string, on the other hand is parsed for key-value pairs and can be accessed with the [`request.query` object](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#flask.Request.args):

```
@route('/end_point')
def like_provider(self):
    foo = request.args.get('foo')
    bar = request.args.get('bar')
```

Comment: So to process `/users?name=Joe+Soap&age=21` I would access the variables by `name = request.args.get('name')` and `age = request.args.get('age')`?

Comment: @b.j.g: exactly. You can specify that `age` should be a Python `int`: `age = request.args.get('age', type=int)` and it'll be converted if possible, or return `None` if not.